# How to output/Input multibyte symbols?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-16, stdstring

After a lot of searching I start using that weird code:

```
ofstream myfile;
    string chars =  "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
    myfile.open ("alphabet.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 66; i+=2) {
        myfile << chars[i] <<chars[i+1] << "\n";
    }
    myfile.close();
```

But is there really no way to get a wide character out of std::string?

Comment: `std::string` contains `char`s, it always contained `char`s, and it will always contains `char`s. With non-Latin characters, one option is to use regional encodings, like KOI8-R, however the use of `KOI8-R` and other characters sets has been deprecated over time, and modern C++ implementations usually default to multibyte UTF-8 to represent non-Latin characters, where each chaacter, like "б" is represented by a multibyte sequence.

Comment: I knew about it, but why there no built-in method to getting such letters?!

Comment: The C++ library does have some classes for transcoding between various encoding and Unicode, but they are awkward to use, and are not very popular. Most application that need to deal with Unicode will use one of several libraries for doing so, like `iconv`.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov I guess because C++ predates the widespread adoption of Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked on my machine.  My source code file is in UTF-8.  The string is in UTF-16.  The output is in UTF-16LE.

C++ has gotten a little better over time handling Unicode strings, but still has a lot of room for improvement.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::ofstream;
using std::string;

int main() {
    auto chars = u"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
    auto myfile = ofstream("alphabet.txt");
    for (char16_t const* p = chars; *p; ++p) {
        auto c = *p;
        auto cc = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&c);
        myfile.write(cc, sizeof c);
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```